# What is the semantics of nested interface on a class?

Tags: java, android

I am reading a book from Big Nerd Ranch regarding Fragments on Tablets. I encountered a code that I haven't encountered when self-learning Java.

```
public interface Callbacks
{
    void onCrimeSelected(Crime crime);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}
```

As you can see, this is a code embedded on a class say ClassA. Therefore, the interface scoping will be ClassA.Callbacks. Now, Activity and ClassA is totally unrelated, and yet I can convert Activity to a Callbacks? Am I missing something here?

This part of the code really baffles me:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}
```

I am confuse on how we could convert unrelated class to another class/interface which belongs to a different scope/hierarchy.

Can someone help me understand this? TIA!

Comment: You can,'t. The Activity itself will need to implement that interface.
One reason why interfaces can be nested, is if they're only intended/expected to be used with that class.

Comment: As I continued reading the book, the hosting activity implements that interface. That should explain it. But its too bizarre for me at the moment. I must admit, I was lost on the author's write up on this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics is: The class expects any `Activity` attaching to it to implement that interface. Via this interface it communicates events to those activities.

The reason why it is a nested interface is: It is intended to be used only in conjunction with this class. It is not a common one. Yet it can be commonly be implemented because it is `public`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. You are right on this one.

Answer (score 1):

The class or interface `Activity` needs to implement `ClassA.Callbacks`. Otherwise the  statement `mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;` would throw an `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Most likely it would either be a subclass (or implementation) of Activity.